# I need stop a macro according to the value of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I need this macro to stop its execution in the gap that I leave if the value of E21 is different from 1

how can I do this?

```
function _1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('E23');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);


   (I NEED STOP HERE IF E21<>1)



  spreadsheet.getRange('E17').activate();

 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('REGISTROS'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
```

Comment: It would be better if you would include the sheet name in the Spreadsheet.getRange("SheetName!A1") as shown in this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)). It might help you to figure out what you were doing when you come back to a script 6 months later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what sheet E21 is on but you can do this

```
if(sheet.getRange('E21').getValue()!=1) return;
```